# AWK/Last Linux Counting Logins

Tags: linux, awk

I want to use the Last -iw command and then filter the output showing only the total number of logins on the left and and the username on the right.

I've tried

```
last | awk '{print count++, $1}'
```

and the results are similar to what I want but it isn't right.

It should look like:

```
TotalNumberOfLogins     UserName

14                           bob

15                           mary
```

and so on..

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some sample output that you want formatted, and the format that you want? What do you mean by TotalNumberOfLogins?

Comment: Can't Post pictures yet sorry :( I mean counting the numbers of times a user has logged in.

Comment: I didn't want a picture, thanks, I wanted you to copy/paste from your screen so I could see your data and use it. I get a couple of lines which shouldn't be there if you use the answer, but if you're happy with it you should consider accepting it (tick outline next to the answer, click on it).

Answer (score 1):

You need to accumulate the number of logins per user into an assocciative array, like this:

```
last | awk '{logins[$1]++}END{for(i in logins){print logins[i], i}}' | sort -nr
```